# C++ Copy any substring between specified indexes of string

Tags: c++, string, substring

I have a question about strings in C++. Assume I have a unicode string like below:

```
std::wstring S = L"NAME: STUPID";
```

And above string can be like `L"AGE: STUPID"`, `L"BEHAVIOR: STUPID"`, `L"BEHAVIOR: STUPID; NAME: ANONYMOUS"`

I want to extract the word `STUPID` from a string like above. The copying should begin at the given word's length (e.g. Length of `NAME` or `BEHAVIOR`) and stop at the first found semicolon (`;`). Copying should be done from main string. (e.g. `L"NAME: STUPID"`).

What I have tried:

```
LPCWSTR ExtractSubStringFromString(LPCWSTR & Type, LPCWSTR & String) {

    std::wstring S = std::wstring(String);

    if (S.find(L";") != std::wstring::npos) // MAIN STRING CONTAINS A SEMICOLON
    {
        std::wstring S = std::wstring(String + std::wstring(Type).length(),  // << CANNOT THINK HOW TO COPY SUBSTRING HERE.
    }
    else { NO SEMICOLON, ONLY CAN BE A ONE WORD }
}
```

Comment: Find the colon `':'`, skip over all possible white-space, and you have the starting position.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I cannot figure out how to do it. :-(

Comment: Have look at [`std::wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). You could use `size()` to get length of contents, `at()` or `operator[]()` to access individual characters. So, what's missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `substr` method of `std::wstring`. This is a working example of what you are trying to achieve:

```
std::wstring ExtractSubStringFromString(const std::wstring String)
{
    std::wstring S = std::wstring(String);

    size_t semicolon = S.find(L';');

    // semicolon found?
    if (semicolon != std::wstring::npos)
    {
        // find colon between string start and semicolon
        size_t colon = S.find(L':', 0);

        if (colon != std::wstring::npos && colon < semicolon)
        {
            // take string after colon to the semicolon
            return S.substr(colon + 1, semicolon - colon - 1);
        }

        // invalid input parameter
        return L"";
    }

    size_t colon = S.find(L':');

    if (colon != std::wstring::npos)
    {
        size_t count = std::wstring::npos;

        if (S[S.length() - 1] == L']')
            count = S.length() - 1 - colon - 1;

        // return substring after colon to the end
        return S.substr(colon + 1, count);
    }


    // invalid input parameter
    return L"";
}
```

Returns `STUPID` for inputs `<anything>: STUPID`, `[<anything>: STUPID]` or `<anything>: STUPID; <anything>: <anything>...`

You might want to take care of whitespace.

Comment: Thanks! It worked fine! But how can I change this to return `STUPID` when I input `[<anything>: STUPID]`? I forgot to mention it in my question. In such condition, this currently returns `STUPID]`. I tried many times, I still getting `STUPID]`. I am very weak in such string operations. :-(

Comment: @Blueeyes789 Just strip trailing `]` if present

Comment: I also thought, but I prefer to return string without it directly from this function.

Comment: I've edited my answer, however you really should experiment and debug this yourself

Comment: Why did you say that I want to take care of whitespaces? Do some functions fail with them?